sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unicode conversion failed
In Docker+FastAPI+SQLAlchemy (mssql+pyodbc) environment, an error occurs when begin with sqlalchemy.
The environment is as follows.
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12.3-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apk update
RUN apk add gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev
RUN apk add bash curl gnupg
RUN apk add gnu-libiconv gnu-libiconv-dev

# RUN apk add curl gpg gpg-agent
#Download the desired package(s)
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/5/355d7943-a338-41a7-858d-53b259ea33f5/msodbcsql18_18.3.3.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/5/355d7943-a338-41a7-858d-53b259ea33f5/mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_amd64.apk

#(Optional) Verify signature, if 'gpg' is missing install it using 'apk add gnupg':
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/5/355d7943-a338-41a7-858d-53b259ea33f5/msodbcsql18_18.3.3.1-1_amd64.sig
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/5/355d7943-a338-41a7-858d-53b259ea33f5/mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_amd64.sig

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import -
RUN gpg --verify msodbcsql18_18.3.3.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql18_18.3.3.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN gpg --verify mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_amd64.sig mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_amd64.apk

#Install the package(s)
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql18_18.3.3.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools18_18.3.1.1-1_amd64.apk

ENV GLIBC_VER=2.35-r1
RUN apk update --no-cache && \
    apk add --no-cache git curl binutils && \
    curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
    curl -sLO "https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk" && \
    curl -sLO "https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk" && \
    apk add --force-overwrite --no-cache glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH=./fast-api

COPY . .
EXPOSE 5002

requirements.txt:
fastapi==0.110.1
uvicorn==0.29.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.29
pandas==2.2.2
pyodbc==5.1.0
email-validator==2.1.1

Error content:
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unicode conversion failed (22) (SQLGetData)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)

database.py：
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
pyodbc.pooling = False

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = sa.engine.url.URL(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username="user",
    password="pass",
    host="hostname",
    port=1433,
    database="test",
    query={
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
        "TrustServerCertificate": "yes",
    },
)
print(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
    , pool_recycle=1500
    )

In my database.py, I tried writing the following, but I get the same error
import pyodbc
pyodbc.pooling = False 

Note:
collation used by the database is Japanese_CI_AS.(Windows Server 2016 Standard MSSQL)
Can someone please help me?
addition：
In the Dockerfile
After adding the following line, the error no longer occurs, but nothing is returned.
FROM python:3.12.3-alpine
WORKDIR /backend
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN apk update
RUN apk add gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev
RUN apk add bash curl gnupg
RUN apk add gnu-libiconv gnu-libiconv-dev
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so <<←ADD!>>


Which collation is used by the database? I found this issue 1479 where they talk about a missing package glibc-gconv-extra. Since your image is based on a lighweight Alpine x musl system you should try a more heavyweight Debian based image with a wider encoding support.

@MartinTovmassian Thanks for your help.
collation used by the database is Japanese_CI_AS.(Windows Server 2016 Standard)Could this be the cause?
I would like to know how to install glibc-gconv-extra on Alpine.If possible, I would like to try Alpine.
I will also try Debian.

glibc-gconv-extra is strongly linked to glibc. I have not enough knowledge on musl but maybe a workaround exists with the alpine-pkg-glibc you already tried to install (or also gcompat). But before going in this direction an other solution should be to install libiconv which is working on Alpine apk add gnu-libiconv-dev and brings Japanese support.

@MartinTovmassian
Thank you for your support.
I followed your advice and tried to install gnu-libiconv-dev and also added alpine-pkg-glibcmo, but the same error occurred.
I will try some more.

Look a the v-makouz answer he mentions to run ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so before running the application.

@MartinTovmassian
I appreciate your kindness.
In the Dockerfile
After adding the following line, the error no longer occurs, but nothing is returned.
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so
I will try some more.
